# Как спрятать статический контент за динамическим URL?

Tags: java, spring

К примеру существуют на веб-сервере папки со статическим контентом, который нужно подгружать в iframe-ах на других сайтах.

```
pano/3dpanorama1/index.html
pano/3dpanorama2/index.html
pano/3dpanorama3/index.html
```

Я хочу генерировать url-ы такого вида:
/getpano/HGDS7D43KGH так чтобы, в зависимости от ID (HGDS7D43KGH) выдавался соответствующий статический контент. 
Например

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/getpano/HGDS7D43KGH"/>
```

Причем index.html в каждой папке подгружает кучу скриптов и другого статического контента по относительному пути pano/3dpanorama1
Как лучше это реализовать? Если приложение на java, а статический контент находится за апачем с настройками:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /css !
ProxyPass /img !
ProxyPass /fonts !
ProxyPass /js !
ProxyPass /pano !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Приложение на java видимо должно из кодированной ссылки получать не кодированную (например расшифровывать строку и получать из id нее id записи в БД, где хранится ссылка на статику) и выдавать обычный redirect на тот url.

Comment: Дело в том что в таком случае браузер просто переходит по редиректу на страницу со статикой pano/3dpanorama1/index.html а нужно чтобы урл оставался http://example.com/getpano/HGDS7D43KGH

Comment: для начала надо понять как остальная статика должна находится, раз пути относительные, то было бы логично что бы например основная страница была на `example.com/getpano/HGDS7D43KGH/` а картинка с этой страницы `example.com/getpano/HGDS7D43KGH/abc.jpg` и тогда мы приходим к тому, что в идеале преобразование путей должно произойти на уровне web-сервера (что бы не потерять скорость отдачи статики), либо все ссылки должны пройти через скрипт, который сам прочитает с диска статику и отдаст клиенту (что медленнее). Остается узнать какой же у вас web-сервер ...

Comment: Сервер Apache/2.2.22, да в идеале было бы сделать средствами апача

Comment: тогда надо копать в сторону динамического rewrite. например скриптом или с использованием БД https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg

Comment: Да, это стоит попробовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Тут нашел как все сделать на java http://www.codemarvels.com/2010/11/apache-mod_rewrite-how-to-use-a-java-program-as-the-rewitemap/